# Counting number of group homomorphism

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Show that 
$$\# \text{hom}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, G)=\# \{f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to G\mid f\; \text{is a homomorphism},2\mathbb{Z}\times 2\mathbb{Z}\subset \text{ker}f \}.$$

Comment: This is very straightforward, what have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Actually I have a solution: a necessary and sufficient condition for $\varphi\in \text{hom}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, G)$ is $\text{ord}\varphi(\bar 1, \bar 0)\mid 2$ and $\text{ord}\varphi(\bar 0, \bar 1)\mid 2$; similarly I can show that a necessary and sufficient condition for $f$ to be in the set on the right is $\text{ord} f(1, 0)\mid 2$ and $\text{ord} f(0, 1)\mid 2$.
But I'm looking for a more elegant (and straightforward as you have said) solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Show that there is a bijection between the two sets whose cardinality you are trying to equate.  The obvious map goes in the $\leftarrow$ direction.

I guess the most elegant thing to do would be to use $(\mathbb{Z \times Z})/(2\mathbb Z \times 2\mathbb Z) \simeq \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and the universal property of quotients.